# Choosing CloudWatch log group dynamically

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a test Grafana setup pointing to my AWS CloudWatch service and CloudWatch logs. I can setup a graph pointing to a specific log group or groups, but what I *want* is to be able to dynamically set the logs groups, e.g., aws/containerinsights/$cluster/application. But I can't see how to do that or whether its even possible. The log group selection appears to be only from a dropdown and can't be edited. Is this possible? If it's not, I don't see how you can create a dashboard that can be used across clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, what looks like a dropdown (for example also dashboard variable) in the Grafana also takes user input - you can write/paste own text there. So write desired string with dashboard variable manually and then use offered `Create: ...` option:

[image]

Comment: Did this work for you? I have been trying this approach but Grafana appears to never want to actually inject to variable. It takes it as a literal.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse - Unfortunately, no. Dashboard variable interpolation doesn't work (there are GitHub issues for that https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues?q=is%3Aissue+variable+cloudwatch+logs)